# React and Redux: Onclick Delete Button Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my code below, I have a delete button that should be deleting the data if clicked. However, when I click on it, I am seeing through console.log that it is returning undefined instead of the id number. Can't seem to figure out why. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

//Actions File

```
export const GET_ITEMS           = 'GET ITEMS';
export const FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH ITEMS SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_ITEMS_ERROR   = 'FETCH ITEMS ERROR';
export const DELETE_ITEM         = 'DELETE_ITEM';

    export const getItems = () => ({
      type: GET_ITEMS
    });
    
    export const deleteItem = (itemId) => ({
      type   : DELETE_ITEM,
      payload: itemId
    });
```

//App.js

```
    class App extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getItems()
      }
    
    static propTypes = {
      getItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      deleteItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }
    handleDelete = (id) =>{
      this.props.deleteItem(id)
      console.log(this.props.deleteItem(id));
    }
    
    
      render() {
    const { itemsList} = this.props.items
        return (
          <div className="container app-wrapper">
            <header>
            {itemsList.map(item => (<h1 key={item.id}>{item.title} <button onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, item.id)}>delete</button></h1>))}
            </header>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      items: state.items
    });
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getItems, deleteItem})(App);
```

Comment: you did a ```console.log(id)``` in ```handleDelete``` function and it returns ```undefined``` ? and can we see the reducer ?

Comment: No when I console.log(id) it returns the correct id. However, when i console.log(this.props.deleteItem(id)) it returns undefined.

Comment: ```console.log(this.props.deleteItem(id))``` can't return you an other value, and does it correctly delete your item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dispatched action **should** return `undefined`, because it does not return anything. You are misunderstanding how data flows in the Redux/reducer pattern.

Here's the basic flow of a Redux update:

1. Action is dispatched.
2. All reducers receive the action object.
3. All reducers return their new or previous state depending on that action's contents.
4. `connect` sees that the Redux state has changed, and triggers a re-render of the children components.
5. You may now use the updated data from your Redux store through props (mapped in `mapStateToProps`).

You cannot call an action and receive the updated state as the return value. It breaks the fundamental pattern of how data flows/updates in Redux.

Comment: Thank you Brian. That makes sense

Comment: Finally resolved the issue. Thank you for this step-by-step explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing your delete action incorrectly in connect. deleteItem expects an id param passed into it.

Try this,

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      items: state.items
    });

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
{
    return {
        deleteItem: (id) => dispatch(actions.deleteItem(id)),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: You don't have to do this... The mapping will keep the function signature and bind dispatch automatically. This just adds an extra function with no extra functionality.